# How to create a transaction that calls a static method of a non-global class?

Tags: oop, abap

I have 1 class, `ZCL_GRID_EVT_HANDLER`, in my ABAP/4 program that has a method `MAIN` that i want to start with a transaction.

I tried right clicking on the program > Create > Transaction
-then chose "Method of a Class (oo transaction)"
-then deselected the checkbox "OO Transaction Model"

-chose my program, chose the class name and the method name, and the message i get is 
"Class ZCL_GID_EVT_HANDLER doesn't exist". (the program is however activated)

help!
Pls tell me what i'm doing wrong or if i'm completelly off tracks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Link the transaction to the program containing the local class and call the `MAIN` method inside that program (at the `START-OF-SELECTION` event).

Comment: that's a great suggestion, and it works. I was however wondering if the default way isn't also available.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'the default way', but transaction codes are limited to global classes. I would recommend to always create global classes with only few exceptions anyway, but that's a long story ;)